# UIView get error: Expected unqualified-id before '=' token

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I declare a UIView in interface:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *textView;
```

Then synthesize it in implementation

```
@synthesize textView;
```

Then call UIView in one of the function:

```
textView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 1024.f, 768.f)];
```

It was OK in simulator but once I change to iPad, I got this error:

```
Expected unqualified-id before '=' token
```

Which part did I done wrong?

But if I change to:

```
UIView * textView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 1024.f, 768.f)];
```

It will run at iPad. But I need to access textView from VC. so what is the best way to resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't saw this error before. So a guess.

Try with:

```
self.textView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 1024.f, 768.f)];
```

You are declaring a property of UIView in your interface, so it's better to access it via getters and setters like:

`self.textView` or `_textView` (If not synthesized)

Comment: Just add UIView *textView; to interface. No need to make property.

Comment: Wow! it works. But I don't quite get it. Care to explain? Thanks Midhun MP.

Comment: @user2310763: in iOS 6, developer's won't declare variable's in interface. They just declare properties according to the scope (In .h or .m)

Comment: user2310763: I take away @property and it give me compile error.

Comment: @sooon: If you didn't declare it as property, then you can't access it via self.textView. Then use textView alone

Comment: Midhun MP: I decided to use your method. Thanks!